# Filling in the date gaps mysql query for ajax call

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way to include empty dates for a time series graph generated from a mysql db.

If I run a query to get say all of the red cars sold on a particular day I could run :

```
SELECT count(car_sale_order) as 'count', DATE(sale_date) as 'sale_date'
FROM car_sales
WHERE colour = "red";
```

but the results could have date holes in them i.e.

```
------------------
count | sale_date
------------------
2     | 2017-09-03
10    | 2017-09-04
1     | 2017-09-07
23    | 2017-09-09
45    | 2017-09-10
2     | 2017-09-11
21    | 2017-09-12
```

when what id really like is :

```
------------------
count | sale_date 
------------------
2     | 2017-09-03
10    | 2017-09-04
0     | 2017-09-05
0     | 2017-09-06
1     | 2017-09-07
0     | 2017-09-08
23    | 2017-09-09
45    | 2017-09-10
2     | 2017-09-11
21    | 2017-09-12
```

I use PHP so know that i could generate this stuff at that side but it would be really handy to just have the result set include this from the get go....

---

This isn't the same as [What is the most straightforward way to pad empty dates in sql results (on either mysql or perl end)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752/what-is-the-most-straightforward-way-to-pad-empty-dates-in-sql-results-on-eithe) 
I'm looking for a MySQL only result

Comment: This may help. https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/

Comment: That looks really handy - ill take a look thanks

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query

Comment: I think the link @Jones gave had the best solution in it I'm just trying to fit it to my use case

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18210324/5930703). I have always found this to be the most reliable way to create date reports as you have a row for every date which you join with your table. In your case, you may wish to use something like:

```
SELECT count(car_sale_order) as 'count', DATE(sale_date) as 'sale_date'
FROM calendar_table
LEFT JOIN car_sales ON calendar_table.date = car_sales.sale_date
WHERE calendar_table.date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31' and colour = "red";
```

Comment: Yeah I have seen this approach before but it doesn't feel clean enough for me - thanks though