# Select Missing Date Ranges In table In Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following Data Table Data as:

```
EMPLOYEEID            DAYDATE
-----------------------------------
101                   01/08/2017
101                   02/08/2017
101                   04/08/2017
101                   06/08/2017
101                   07/08/2017
102                   01/08/2017
102                   03/08/2017
102                   06/08/2017
```

I want to Write a Query to get the following missing Dates between 
01/8/2017 to
07/08/2017 Data as :

```
EMPLOYEEID            DAYDATE
-----------------------------------
101                   03/08/2017
101                   05/08/2017
101                   07/08/2017
102                   02/08/2017
102                   04/08/2017
102                   05/08/2017
102                   07/08/2017
```

How to deal with That?!

Comment: This has been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207721/find-missing-dates-from-date-range

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find missing dates from date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207721/find-missing-dates-from-date-range)

Comment: @kazzi - not an exact duplicate, since here the OP also has different EMPLOYEEID, which complicates the problem.

Comment: Do you need to do this just for the two employees you showed? Or - MUCH BETTER! - do you have another table where ALL the EMPLOYEEID's are present (and EMPLOYEEID is primary key)? So, for example, what if there is EMPLOYEEID = 103, who is not present in your first table AT ALL - doesn't he have to be shown in the output, with ALL the dates considered to be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Either use a Date table, which I think is better, or use a Derived table to populate the dates(many codes available in google under "Oracle How to generate dates") :

```
SELECT t.employeeid,s.date
FROM (SELECT distinct p.employeeid FROM YourTable p) t
CROSS JOIN ( DATE TABLE \ Derived Table) s
```

This query will generate the entire range of dates for each employee. If you want only those that are missing:

```
SELECT t.employeeid,s.date
FROM (SELECT distinct p.employeeid FROM YourTable p) t
CROSS JOIN ( DATE TABLE \ Derived Table) s
LEFT JOIN YourTable h
 ON(h.employeeID = t.employeeId and h.date = s.date)
WHERE h.employeeID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all the rows with a hierarchical query:

```
SELECT DATE '2017-08-01' + LEVEL - 1 AS dt
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY DATE '2017-08-01' + LEVEL - 1 <= DATE '2017-08-07'
```

or a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```
WITH alldates ( dt ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2017-08-01' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT dt + 1 FROM alldates WHERE dt < DATE '2017-08-07'
)
SELECT * FROM alldates
```

Then you can use a partitioned outer join combine it with your existing data nad filter for those missing rows:

```
WITH alldates ( dt ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2017-08-01' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT dt + 1 FROM alldates WHERE dt < DATE '2017-08-07'
)
SELECT employeeId,
       dt
FROM   alldates d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       your_table t
       PARTITION BY ( t.employeeID )
       ON ( t.daydate = d.dt )
WHERE  daydate IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table EMPLOYEE in which EMPLOYEEID is primary key - and assuming that there may be employees who don't appear in your DATA_TABLE at all, and they must be then included in your output:

```
select e.employeeid, d.daydate
from   employee e cross join ( select date '2017-08-01' + level - 1 as daydate
                                 from dual
                                 connect by level <= 7
                             ) d
where  (e.employeeid, d.daydate) not in (select employeeid, daydate from data_table)
;
```